# Ergonomic solution to switch between hide/show Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I know you can hide/show Windows 7 taskbar by right-clicking it, opening the Properties menu and check/uncheck "Auto-hide the taskbar", however this is a long process, I am looking for a more straightforward solution, like for example a simple button to click on the task bar.
Is there any application that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would [taskbar eliminator](http://www.aviassin.com/taskbareliminator) be of use to you? Just press alt+t to toggle the taskbar's availability.

[*Hide Taskbar*](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/hide-taskbar-windows-7-hotkey) might also be good.

Comment: **Hide Taskbar** looked cool, but you cannot access the desktop space that was behind the taskbar even when it's hidden. However **Taskbar Eliminator** did the job. Thanks!